# Postman Request body data from Excel / CSV file - forward slash

Tags: csv, postman, export-to-csv, postman-collection-runner

I get Request body data from Excel file.
I have already covert Excel to CSV format.
I have kind of able to find a solution but it is not working 100% as jsonbody format in not fetching data correctly is shows forward slash in CSV import data from runner collections.

[image: Excel file data]

Request Body

```
{{jsonBody}}
```

Set Global variables jsonBody

Run collection select data file as CSV file as per screenshot request body shows with forward slash.

After running the collection I'm getting body incorrect version with forward slash.

[image: response body incorrect]

This below screenshot show correct version on CSV data I require to remove forward slash from CSV data

[image: CORRECT version for body]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with postman and realized my problem was more of a syntax issue.

Lets say your cvs file has the following columns:

```
        userId |    mid    | platform | type | ...etc
row1    94J4J  | 209444894 |   NORTH  |  PT  | ...
row2    324JE  | 934421903 |   SOUTH  |  MB  | ...
row3    966RT  | 158739394 |   EAST   |  PT  | ...
```

> This is how you want your json request body to look like:

```
  {
    "userId" : "{{userId}}",
       "mids":[{
              "mid":"{{mid}}",
         "platform":"{{platform}}"
               }],
       "type":["{{type}}"],
        .. etc   
   }
```

Make sure your colums names match the varibales {{variableName}}

Answer (score -1):

The data coming from CSV is already in a stringified format so you don't need to do anything in pre-request.

example:

**let csv be**

```
|    jsonBody       |
|    {"name":"user"}|
```

**Now in postman request just use:**

```
{{jsonBody}}
```

as {{column_name}} will be considered as data varaible so , in your case {{jsonBody}}

csv:

[image]

make sure you save this as csv file :

[image]

Now in request use :

[image]

output:

[image]

if you want to add the json body as value of another then just use :

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: in response ? where are you seeing this ?

Comment: please add that screenshot

Comment: in your question there are two screenshots and both are from request body. The second one is the correct one

Comment: there is no response screenshot both are request body screenshot in question

Comment: please remove this line  pm.globals.set("jsonBody",JSON.stringify(pm.iterationData.toObject())); , the variable "jsonBody" gets created automatically , in postman columnname = variable name . so you can refer the data directly as jsonBody, don't have to stringify and create a varaible

Comment: Please add a sensible comment when downvoting

Comment: okay but still still I'm getting this extra \ forward splash in response .{\"userId\":\"{{cl.yyyyyyyyyy8}}\",\"mids\":[{\"mid\":\"{{20955512345}}\",\"platform\":\"NORTH\"}],\"type\": –  Removing pm.globals.set("jsonBody",JSON.stringify(pm.iterationData.toObject())); is not require I get that but its not resolving forward slash . as per answer @PDHide it I already have {{jsonBody}}